# Activate aurelia canDeactivate() life-cycle hook manually

Tags: aurelia

I have two types of routes in my application, routes to aurelia app itself and some external routes. I'm using `href` property to specify external routes. in example below `Task` is a such external route.

```
{
    "name": "dashboard",
    "route": "dashboard",
    "moduleId": "../dashboard/dashboard",
    "settings": {
        "icon": "chart-bar",
        "helpPageId": "_30000"
    },
    "title": "routes:root.dashboard",
    "nav": 25
},
{
    "name": "tasks",
    "settings": {
        "icon": "check-square",
        "helpPageId": "_40000"
    },
    "title": "routes:root.tasks",
    "nav": 30,
    "href": "Task"
}
```

When a user have made some changes in an aurelia route I am using `canDeactivate` hook to display a custom dialog box to the user, asking to discard changes or save changes.

```
canDeactivate(): Promise<boolean> {
    //helper method having dialog box logic
    return this.helperMethod.canDiscardChanges(this.modelTracker.isChanged(this.model), this.deactivateSaveCallback.bind(this));
}
```

But the problem is when I navigate to an external route this hook is not activated. This is understandable because aurelia router is not responsible for that. What I tried to do was bind a method with `beforeunload` event, and then activate the `canDeactivate` manually.

```
async activate(params: any): Promise<void> {
        // some logic
    window.addEventListener("beforeunload", this.onDomWindowBeforenload);
}

onDomWindowBeforeunload: (event: BeforeUnloadEvent) => void = event => {
    this.canDeactivate();
}

async deactivate(): Promise<void> {
    window.removeEventListener("beforeunload", this.onDomWindowBeforeunload);
}
```

This shows the intended dialog box, but does not wait for user to do anything, it is same as previous, just goes to the specified route after showing the dialog. Any help is appericiated.

Comment: Quick thought, have you perhaps looked into [route pipelines](https://aurelia.io/docs/routing/configuration#pipelines)? Perhaps with a certain step you might catch the right event in there?